# Fix for runny pecan pie

Tags: pie

I have read the boards from people who ask what they can do with a pecan pie that did not set up and all the responses are what the cook should have done from the beginning. That doesn't help.  Is there something I can do NOW to fix it?  Should I try baking it more?  Should I microwave it?  Help!!

Answer (score 1):

let it sit out and dehydrate a bit?

fold it into vanilla ice cream?

next time:
more egg in the filling
or
use less filling
or
lower temp/longer bake time

Comment: If dehydrating is a good idea, it'd probably be faster to do in a low-temperature oven (say 200F/95C), low enough that it shouldn't brown the crust much more.

Comment: to add to @Jefromi answer, you may wish to wrap the pie crust's edges with aluminum foil, shiny side out to prevent further browning of the crust.

Answer (score 1):

If I had a couple hours or more, Id try to refrigerate a runny pie. Maybe the filling will gel in the fridge but it would take a little time.